# Spark Issue with insertIntoJDBC

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I 'm trying to develop with the new Dataframe API, but I'm 
getting an error.

I have an existing oracle database and I want to insert rows.
I create a Dataframe from an RDD, then use the "insertIntoJDBC" function.
It appear that dataframes reorder the data inside them.
As a result, I get an error because the fields are not inserted in the 
proper
order.

Is there a way to specify the name or the order of my variables inside the
database?

If it is a bug, here is an example to reproduce it:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

public class ErilView implements Serializable {

    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<user>/<password>@<database>";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_NAME";

    private static final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(
            new SparkConf().setAppName("ErilView"));

    private static final SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(
            sc);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaRDD<Person> rows = sc.textFile("path/dataset/sample.txt").map(
                new Function<String, Person>() {
                    public Person call(String line) throws Exception {
                        String[] fields = line.split("|");

                        Person person = new Person();
                        person.setName(fields[0]);
                        person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(fields[1].trim()));

                        return person;
                    }
                });


        DataFrame schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, Person.class);

        // Option 1: Create new table and insert all records.
        schemaPeople.createJDBCTable(CONNECTION_URL, TABLE_NAME, true);

        // Option 2: Insert all records to an existing table.
        schemaPeople.insertIntoJDBC(CONNECTION_URL, TABLE_NAME, false);
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know any way to populate data in right order.

Thanks in Advance
--Chaitu

Comment: Please attach the stack trace under your code

Comment: Please, remove "spark-java" tag, it's not related to Apache Spark, and this just confuses.

Answer (score 0):

java reflection does not guarantee ordering of properties. Please refer to javadoc for reflection. Here spark tries to pull the properties of your pojo through reflection. 
However there is another way to create the df through structtype schema where ordering of table columns will be remain same.